# React Native refresh screen / component / change state

Tags: react-native, components, refresh, react-navigation

I am using react-native, nested react-navigation, SectionLists,  ActionSheet, etc and I am having hard times setting up a decent way of refreshing components / screens. As I have a few different cases, I have also tried different approaches with no luck.

Examples: 
- Sending a callback function as a param in the navigator when transitioning from one screen to another for state change.
- Assigning AsyncStorage.getItem straight to a state variable (e.g: used on a ListView) and expect it to refresh.

I've seen many questions in the react-navigation git repo (mainly on how to refresh a screen), and recent suggestion to the project on the best approach for future releases, that got me asking if this is something that is in place already.

I can say though, that I've successfully used redux to check the connection state (NetInfo), that although I couldn't yet port the same idea to a different schenario, I think that it is my best approach.

At the moment I have one schenario, that if solved, I believe will answer a few questions I have. For example:

I have a list of news in my Home screen and a few options in my Drawer navigator that I would like to, when clicked, to sort the Home list, without having to call navigate('screen_name') as I would like to, to still keep the Drawer opened after clicked.

What would be the best approach for this ?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One approach you could follow is:
On click on a DrawerNavigator item, you can dispatch an action which would intern change the state by a value. Eg: filterBy: . This store value can be passed as a prop to your home screen, which would intern contain a logic to filter based on that value.

I havent worked with DrawerNavigator but i feel onPress on each item in drawer navigation can be prevented and a action can be invoked at the same place.

Comment: Hi there, thanks for your feedback! Really appreciate it. Yes, that would be using redux, which I think is definitely the best approach for this issue. Exactly, as long as there's no "navigate to" action involved, I might be able to keep the Drawer open. Have to give it a full try. I also just found out that I might be able to fix the other situations by using "extraData" property from SectionList / FlatList's for instance.